# SQL query is returning the wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

At the top of my file I have checked what the `$clientid` is using `echo $clientid`. This echoes 731.

Further down the script I'm running this query:

```
$active_ts = db_select("SELECT * FROM `timesheets` WHERE clientid='".$clientid."' AND status=\"client\" OR status=\"cand\"");
var_dump($active_ts);
```

What I expect to happen is only timesheets with a `clientid` of 731 to be chosen.

What the `var_dump` shows however is `["clientid"]=> string(3) "345"`, `["clientid"]=> string(3) "712"`, ["candid"]=> string(3) "730" and `["clientid"]=> string(3) "721"`

I don't really know how to debug this further....

Comment: try to use brackets () when using 'or' conditions in query. like  "AND (status='client' or status='cand')"

Comment: Don't forget to espace your values. You are using Drupal I guess, use their active records functions to achieve a simple query.

Comment: it looks like a ( ) problem. If I read what you want, it's "(clientid=731 ET status=client) OR (status=cand). Try with
`SELECT * FROM timesheets WHERE clientid='".$clientid."' AND (status=\"client\" OR status=\"cand\")`

Comment: Choose either single or double quotes and stick with one. Also, if `clientid` is a number then you do not have to quote it. Further more, you should consider using parenthesis to group related expressions. For example, `A and (B or C)` is not the same as `(A and B) or C `. If you understand in which order they are evaluated then it is not strictly necessary, but it makes your code much easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because query select user with `status = cand`.

You need to change your query :

### Change :

```
$active_ts = db_select('
    SELECT * FROM `timesheets` 
    WHERE clientid='.$clientid.' AND (status="client" OR status="cand")
');
```

I think you don't need `'` between `clientid` because it's int.

Comment: Okay thanks - for this query `$active_tsquery = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheets WHERE status=\"cand\" OR status=\"client\" ORDER BY weekending ASC");` should I rewrite it as `$active_tsquery = db_select("SELECT * FROM timesheets WHERE (status=\"cand\" OR status=\"client\") ORDER BY weekending ASC");`

Comment: No, because you are testing 2 values, not 3. You can but it's not necessary.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron The second query would still work though right? Just thinking to get into the habit of adding parentheses, or is this not recommended

Comment: Like I say, You can but it's not necessary. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `timesheets`
WHERE clientid = '".$clientid."' AND status = 'client' OR status = 'cand'
```

The `WHERE` clause has no parentheses.  It is interpreted as:

```
WHERE (clientid = '".$clientid."' AND status = 'client') OR status = 'cand'
```

This is presumably not what you want.  I would suggest you use `IN`:

```
WHERE clientid = '".$clientid."' AND status  IN ('client', 'cand')
```